# Visual Studio 2013 multiple break points at specific search keyword

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I'm search in **Entire Solution** for a specific key word 
Ex: `int counter;` 

I want to put multiple break points at the result 
in the example : I want here break points at

```
Class1,Class2,Class3..etc. at the "int counter;" line
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just double click on the line in the search result, and press ctrl+B, it will put break point there. Same way do it for other 3 lines too.

(Or)
Press ctrl+alt+B, it will open breakpoint window, then click new int left top side of breakpoint window and click at break at function, give your function name, check the intellisense checkbox, it will put breakpoints wherever that function is referred.

Comment: Sorry but I need to break point at certain line of code ,ex: search for "int counter;" this search get 100 result, i don't want to keep clicking for each one i'm searching for a way to put a break points at them all at once.